# Cannot access BigQuery from DataFlow SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to join some data from a pubsub with a bigquery table

```
select 
  st.*,
  wo.workorder
from pubsub.topic.newcobi.sensor_ticks as st
left join 
  bigquery.table.newcobi.masterdata.workorders as wo on st.machine_id = wo.machine
```

This should be quite similar to the examples on the google tutorials. But it consistently fails with:

```
Error message from worker: java.io.IOException: Failed to start reading from source: org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter@6283e583 
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$UnboundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:792)
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: BigQuery storage source must be split before reading 
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryStorageSourceBase.createReader(BigQueryStorageSourceBase.java:169) 
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryStorageTableSource.createReader(BigQueryStorageTableSource.java:43) 
(...)
```

This happens no matter if I write the results to bigquery or to pubsub. So: How do I split the table before reading?

Thanks

Stefan

Comment: just to confirm - are you doing this from the Dataflow SQL UI? also, what's the size of your BQ table?

Comment: any updates to this question?